# CD microservices installation for LIVE and STAGING targets

Tags: content-delivery, powershell, microservices

I want to set up CD instance for two targets in Tridion Topology Manager - Live & Staging.
As I understand I need to install CD services both for Live & Staging (as a result I will have pairs at least of the following microservices: discovery context, deployer). I will also have Session Preview and Session Content for Stagindg and Content microservice for Live target.

The question is how to set up with powershell different port numbers for pairs of services (discovery context, deployer)? Should I edit the scripts for installation of each target or there are parameters that allow to install without editing scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You need to edit the scripts for all services and update the following variables $name, $displayName, $description, $serverPort.

We also need to update $dependsOn variable while registering services with Discovery Service.

While update Port number ensure that assign only Unused port numbers, it should not conflict with other services.

Comment: So, am I right that I should edit the following installation script e.g. discovery:
SDL Web 8.5\Content Delivery\roles\deployer\deployer\standalone\bin\installService.ps1

Comment: Yes, You are right

Comment: So is it a possible way to change needed installation scripts for needed services and then install with 'quickinstall.ps1' for Live target. Then repeat these steps for Staging target. Should this work?

Answer (score 5):

Avoid editing the scripts unless you really run into something that cannot be set with a parameter. You should be able to pass in parameters for everything, though.

Some common parameters:

- **--Name** lets you set the short name of the service.
- **--DisplayName** lets you set the user-friendly name (visible in the Services list)
- **--Description** lets you set the description of the service
- **--DependsOn** will have the service depend on another service (most commonly the Discovery Service for that instance). Note that this only makes sense if both services are running on the same machine.
- **--server.port** lets you set the port the service will run on.
- **-D*prop*=*value*** lets you specify any number of JVM options and variables used within configuration files (e.g. *-Ddbname=UDP_Broker_Staging* will change the database name to UDP_Broker_Staging)

For example:

```
.\installService.ps1 --DisplayName="UDP Content Service (Staging)" --Name="UDPContentServiceStaging" --DependsOn="UDPDiscoveryServiceStaging" --server.port="9081"
```

Comment: I usually create a separate script that calls installService.ps1 with parameters. For an example of powershell code that generates such a script see: https://github.com/TridionPractice/autoInstall/blob/master/SetupContentDelivery.ps1#L66